# Project Euler #3 Efficiency

Tags: java, programming-challenge

I'd like to reduce the complexity of my code

**Problem :**

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of a given number N?

**Solution :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
            int input = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(calculateFactors(input));

        }
    }

    public static int calculateFactors(int input) {
        TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
        while (input % 2 == 0) {
            set.add(2);
            input = input / 2;
        }
        for (int i = 3; i < Math.sqrt(input); i = i + 2) {
            while (input % i == 0) {
                set.add(i);
                input = input / i;
            }
        }
        if (input > 2) {
            set.add(input);
        }
        int max = set.last();
        return max;
    }

}
```

Comment: Efficiency and complexity are not exact antonyms.

Comment: Is it just me or does the title of your question read like the title of a Big Bang Theory episode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Correctness:

[Project Euler Problem #3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) asks for 
the largest prime factor of 600851475143, and that number exceed the range
of the `int` data type. (Your program aborts with an exception for this input value.) You have to use `long` instead.

In

```
for (int i = 3; i < Math.sqrt(input); i = i + 2) { ... }
```

the `<` should be replaced by `<=`, otherwise you get a wrong result if the
input is the square of a prime number (such as `25`). To avoid a loss of precision if `input` is converted to a floating point
number, it should be

```
for (long i = 3; i * i <= input; i = i + 2) { ... }
```

#### Efficiency:

The problem is about the *largest* prime factor. Your algorithm already 
determines the prime factors in increasing order. Therefore there is no need
to store the prime factors in a collection to get its maximum value.
It is sufficient to remember the last prime factor found.

#### Putting it together:

Your function (renamed slightly) would then look like

```
public static long calculateLargestFactor(long input) {
    long largestFactor = 1;
    while (input % 2 == 0) {
        largestFactor = 2;
        input = input / 2;
    }
    for (long i = 3; i * i <= input; i = i + 2) {
        while (input % i == 0) {
            largestFactor = i;
            input = input / i;
        }
    }
    if (input > 2) {
        largestFactor = input;
    }
    return largestFactor;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 3; i < Math.sqrt(input); i = i + 2) {
```

You're computing `sqrt` on each iteration, which wastes more time then the useful work (modulus computation) takes. Using

```
for (long i = 3; i * i <= input; i = i + 2) {
```

is fine(*), as multiplication is much faster than division, using something like

```
long limit = (long) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(input));
for (long i = 3; i <= limit; i = i + 2) {
```

is possibly better.

---

(*) Note that `input` changes during the iterations and the correctness is not  obvious. Fortunately, it's correct.

I guess, the fastest solution (apart from smarter and complicated algorithms) would be using the `limit` as above and recomputing it whenever a divisor is found. But it's no big improvement.