# Project Euler 3: Largest prime factor

Tags: java, programming-challenge, primes

How can I improve my code, make it more efficient, and are there any tips you have?

[Project Euler 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3):

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

```
public class LargestPrimeFactor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long num = 600851475143L;
        boolean isPrime = true;

        // this is to see if num is factorable
        for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {


            //if i is a factor, check if its prime
            if (num % i == 0) {

                for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {


                    if (i % j == 0) {

                        isPrime = false;

                    }

                }

                if (isPrime) {

                    System.out.println(i);

                }

            }   

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I believe `int i` and `int j` should be `long i` and `long j` respectively. (More than believe, I know it to be true.) You're falling into an integer overflow issue, as the value `num` is larger than the max value of an `int`, so, `i` wraps back around to 0 and throws an exception.

Comment: I ran your code and it printed all the prime factors instead of just the largest one, I also got a divide-by-zero error later because the value of `i` overflowed the maximum integer. It sounds like the code is not working correctly. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Your algorithm could be made much more efficient. Here's a hint: if a and b are coprime (that is: a and b have no prime factors in common), but a divides b*c, then a must divide c.

Comment: Compare http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67201/project-euler-3-efficiency.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A small note first, please do not double-space all lines in code, it just makes it harder to read, rather than easier.

#### Integer overflow

Using an [`int` primitive type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for `i` and `j` is causing the number to go through [integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3001995/3626537) and go back to its minimum value -2,147,483,648 (or \$-2^{31}\$),  once it exceeds the maximum value 2,147,483,647 (or \$2^{31}-1\$), then finally all the way back from there to \$0\$, resulting in a `java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero`. To correct this, use a `long` type for the iterators instead:

```
    // this is to see if num is factorable
    for (long i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        //if i is a factor, check if its prime
        if (num % i == 0) {
            for (long j = 2; j < i; j++) {
```

#### Algorithm

With the above problem fixed, we can now see that the algorithm you use has a few problems. Given the number \$n = 600851475143\$

1. It checks every number \$i\$ in the set \$[2,3,4, \ldots, n-1]\$ to see if it is a factor of \$n\$.
2. For each \$i\$, it then checks every number \$j\$ in the set \$[i, i+1, i+2,\ldots, n-2]\$ to see if it is prime.
3. It returns each number that matches both criteria, e.g., 71, 839, 1471 and finally the answer, and then *it just keeps on going* until \$i = 600851475143 - 1\$, which takes a ***very long time***.

[The "right" algorithm](/a/48185/9357) is very simple, and involves no primality testing. I left an explanation of it in the code comments. This finds the right answer in less than 1 second. There would be other ways to improve it to be more Java/object-oriented, but for the sake of a math exercise like this it should do pretty nicely. Here is a [live demo](https://repl.it/C8UA/1) as well.

```
class LargestPrimeFactor  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long N = 600851475143L;

        // First, start from the maximum number and divide by 2
        // until you can no longer divide evenly by 2, i.e., the number is odd
        while (N % 2 == 0) {

            // in the case of 600851475143 this will be skipped entirely since it is an odd number, 
            // but for the sake of generality we will keep it so it can be used on any number
            N /= 2;
        }

        // the next prime number is 3, and all prime numbers from there are odd numbers,
        // so we can safely just add 2 to the factor each time and only test for odd numbers
        // note that this has a small inefficiency in that it will also test for a few non-prime odd numbers
        // like 9, 15, 21, etc. but it's much less computational work to try dividing by a candidate factor than to test for primality.
        for (long factor = 3; factor < N; factor += 2) {

            // if N is evenly divisible by the factor, then we just divide it, and we keep going
            // until N can no longer be divided by a number smaller than itself,
            // in other words, until N is a prime number
            while (N % factor == 0 && factor < N) {
                N /= factor;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The answer is " + N);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code fails if the largest prime factor is multiple (squared or higher). e.g., if N=25 it will return 1 instead of 5. Changing the condition N%factor==0 to N%factor==0&&factor<N fixes that.

Comment: It's possible that it does @MeniRosenfeld, if that was a bigger program instead of just a PE problem we should definitively think about those special cases

Comment: Ok, but keep in mind that a priori we don't know that for this particular PE problem the number is not of this form, so we might as well write a program that is guaranteed to work.

Comment: That's a fair enough critique @MeniRosenfeld and I think maybe you should write an answer about it. In any case though, thank you. Sounds like there should be a "pivot" type of value that changes the way it's handled

Answer (score 8):

> ```
>             //if i is a factor, check if its prime
> ```

It may be pedantic, but "its" should have an [apostrophe](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/apostrophe) in it if it is used as a contraction for "it is".

```
            // if i is a factor, check if it's prime
```

You are saying "check if it is prime".

More importantly, you don't need to check if the factors are prime if you do it right.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long num = 600851475143L;
        long i = 2;
        for ( ; i <= num; i++) {
            //if i is a factor, remove it
            while (num % i == 0) {
                num /= i;
            }
        }

        // the last number must be prime
        System.out.println(i-1);
    }
```

When this finds a factor, it removes it from `num` until the new `num` is no longer divisible by that factor.  As a result, if `num` isn't prime, it's pretty fast.  It is (mostly) linear in time relative to the answer.

Note that we can improve things by writing special cases for 2 and 3.  Also, the worst behavior occurs when `num` is prime.  If you check for that first, you can limit the worst case to \$O(\sqrt n)\$.

```
public class Euler3 {

    public long calculateLargestPrimeFactor(long number) {
        long current = 1;

        while (number % 2 == 0) {
            number /= 2;
            current = 2;
        }

        while (number % 3 == 0) {
            number /= 3;
            current = 3;
        }

        if (number == 1) {
            return current;
        }

        current = 5;
        int increment = 4;
        int sqrt_num = (int) Math.sqrt(number);
        for ( ; current <= number; current += increment) {
            if (current > sqrt_num) {
                return number;
            }

            // if current is a factor, remove it
            while (number % current == 0) {
                number /= current;
            }

            increment = 6 - increment;
        }

        // the last number must be prime
        return current - increment;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(calculateLargestPrimeFactor(600851475149L));
        System.out.println(calculateLargestPrimeFactor(600851475143L));
        System.out.println(calculateLargestPrimeFactor(2 * 600851475149L));
        System.out.println(calculateLargestPrimeFactor(20));
        System.out.println(calculateLargestPrimeFactor(22));
        System.out.println(calculateLargestPrimeFactor(1073741824));
        System.out.println(calculateLargestPrimeFactor(6561));
    }

}
```

Note that it would be more robust to do the `main` testing in JUnit or similar.

I also changed the name of `i` and `num` to `current` and `number` respectively to be clearer.

Answer (score 3):

## Performance

You can use a Sieve of Eratosthenes to make it faster.

This is a slightly more complicated sieve as it only sieves the odd numbers up to the square root of the input

```
public long largestPrimeFactor( final long input ) {
  // Initialise a BitSet for the sieve.
  final BitSet sieve = new BitSet( ((int) Math.sqrt( input )) + 1 );

  // Find if there are factors of 2 and eliminate them.
  long i = Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(input);
  long value      = input >> i;
  long maxPrime   = i > 0 ? 2 : 1;

  // Loop only over the values which remain in the sieve (i.e. the primes)
  for ( int j = 1; (i = (j<<1)+1) * i <= value; j = sieve.nextClearBit( j + 1 ) ){
    sieve.set(j);

    // Check if it is a factor
    if ( value % i == 0 )
    {
      maxPrime = i;
      // Eliminate the factor
      do value /= i; while( value % i == 0 );
      if ( value == 1 )
        break;
    }

    // Iterate through the sieve setting all the multiples
    // of the current value to be non-prime.
    for ( long k = (i*i-1)>>1; k * k <= value; k += i )
      sieve.set( (int) k);
  }

  return value > 1 ? value : maxPrime;
}
```

For small numbers, using a simple algorithm will be faster but if you (a) can re-use the sieve when finding/testing multiple numbers or (b) are using it for large numbers; then a sieve is likely to be faster.

Comment: I'm not sure that Sieve of Eratosthenes can solve Project Euler 3 in any reasonable time, I've tried it before and I gave up waiting after it had been computing for over 12 minutes without giving the answer...

Comment: @Phrancis The code above runs in about the same time (i.e. completes it in ~13μs on my machine) as the accepted answer for Project Euler 3. However, if you modify it so the sieve is a class attribute and maintain the sieve between runs then you start to see significant speed-ups (after initially populating the sieve) and the sieve is about 50% faster (in my tests) than the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh wow, I must have done something really inefficient in my Sieve then, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

## Efficiency

1. Check only odd numbers
2. Check only numbers to the square root of the number under test
3. You maybe want to count down instead of count up

## Robustness

1. You should have a look at BigInteger to avoid overflows and you think about numbers exceeding the Long-Type. This will not be easy.
2. You should not compare Integer-Values with Long-Values as you are using them within the same semantic. Harmonize the algorithm to use only one type for one purpose (in this case Long)

## Naming

1. You have algorithms but no names. Break your algorithm in parts and name them meaningfully